# IIS ISAPI CGI - How to configure the number of concurrent thrreads?

Tags: iis, cgi, threadpool, isapi

Good day.

I found many information about how to configure the number of concurrent threads for ASP applications. But what about ISAPI and CGI written without ASP?

I have few CGI applications that need to handle a multiple concurrent requests. And I want to set a number of concurrent threads for that. How can I do it?

Also it will be interesting to get some info about are there some limits on the number of concurrent requests that IIS ISAPI CGI can handle in a default configuration.

Thank you.

Comment: you should try asking for "concurrent worker processes", not threads, because when you use CGI, one process handles at most one request simultaneously IIRC